# Exit WCF service in IIS Express from code

Tags: c#, wcf, iis-express

Like what I say in the title, how can we exit that service (which starting together with the client application) when we turn off the client app? I try to call `_serviceClient.CloseAsync()` but the service still there in IIS Express. So do we have any way to do it?

**UPDATE:**
My service is handle camera and stream the image to the client side. So if I don't exit the service, it will hold the camera until we turn it off from IIS manually. So I want to turn off two sides together.

I handled the release camera function in Close-action off the app. but sometime that unexpected, the app is crashed so that code isn't run.

Comment: Client and service are two different things. You can not shut down the service from client? How do you start the service from client if it's not running at all and not taking up any requests? What's the actual requirements? Why you want to have this feature in your service?

Comment: You can set an idle timeout in IIS to "suspend" the service if idle for too long. It will be started again automatically if some client is trying to reach it. No client should be able to shut down a service.

Comment: After update: Doing this via Service shutdown is the wrong way to go. a) Create an API so the client can actively stop the streaming. b) Detect in server if someone is actually listening to the stream and stop it if not. For example you could use a "dead-man" switch. I.e. clients must send a heartbeat to keep the stream alive.

Comment: @Fildor please take a look at my second update. :)

Comment: I edited my second comment, too :)

Comment: The example is awesome, thank you. It's exactly what I am looking for,

Comment: Can you write it to an answer so other people can find this solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly this problem arises when the sender is not aware of the listener being terminated. For example in UDP streaming.

One solution is to have the listener send "heartbeat" messages to indicate it is still there and listening at a certain interval. If the heartbeat is not received any more, the server can conclude the client is not listening any more for whatever reason and free resources ( stop stream, release camera ... ).

Mind that UDP is not reliable, so single heartbeats may go missing. You'll have to see what exactly the perfect configuration of heartbeat-frequency and "missing beats"-tolerance will work for you and the network.

A common pattern for this is to implement a protocol, in which the client must send "acknowledge" - messages to the server to indicate received packages (since UDP packages of the stream could also need to be resent).

Comment: I'm using HTTP protocol in my WCF service. So could you give me more information about the pattern that you mentioned?